# Get SSL Certificate expiration WITHOUT openssl command

Tags: mysql, ssl, base64, ssl-certificate

I apologize if this is an ignorant question, but is there a way to get the expiration time from an SSL cert without running an SSL command in the terminal?

When I base64 decode the contents of the cert, some of the output is readable, but a lot of it is not. The readable parts do not contain the expires information from what I can see.

To be candid on my case, I am trying to run a MySQL command to get information on stored SSL certs. So if there is a trick for MySQL, that would be cool too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this text buried near the end of the second line in the base64 decoded cert: `150923190324Z160922190324Z`

This apparently contains the information I was looking for. This contains the `notBefore` and `notAfter` times, each containing 12 digits followed by a `Z`.

The format is `YYMMDDHHMMSS`. So in the example above i get:

```
Not Before: Sep 23 19:03:24 2015 GMT
Not After : Sep 22 19:03:24 2016 GMT
```

All without running an `openssl` command and only using base64 decoding.